# How do I get emacs to autoexpand from a list of known keywords?

Tags: emacs, python, autocomplete

On a Ubuntu installation I have both `python-mode.el` and the command in my `.emacs` file:

```
(global-set-key [f2] 'hippie-expand)
```

Thus keywords are highlighted and variables that I have defined already can be autoexpanded with `[f2]`. How can I get the autoexpand to work with the python keywords? For example, given the code

```
for x in enumera
```

By pressing `[f2]` how can I get this to expand to

```
for x in enumerate
```

([`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) is a known keyword). Since I'm learning emacs, the more detail in the answer, the more it would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you might prefer to use one of the packages [auto-complete](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete) or [jedi](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/).

That said, `hippie-expand` works by trying to expand the current word using a list of functions, stored in the variable `hippie-expand-try-functions-list` (to view its contents, press `C-h v hippie-expand-try-functions-list RET`). For instance, the first function in the default value for that variable tries to expand a filename. `hippie-expand` asks for an expansion for each function in turn, moving to the next when a function has exhausted all of its possible completions. (That is, you may keep pressing `[f2]` to get more expansions.)

When you expand the name of a variable that already appears in your python code, `hippie-expand` is using the function `try-expand-dabbrev`, which searches for the current word in the current buffer. Another function on that list, `try-expand-dabbrev-all-buffers`, searches for the current word in all open buffers. Thus, a quick (and dirty) solution to your problem would be to create a file with all keywords and built-ins (`enumerate` is a built-in), and keep that file opened in emacs. That is, if you insist on using `hippie-expand`; clearly the two packages I mentioned before seem like better solutions if you can get them to work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll probably end up using one of the packages, but learn quite a bit from trying to do it myself!